# How to make GitHub Workflow status as skipped if a particular job skips

Tags: github-actions

In my GitHub workflow I had to add a Pre-CI job to get the commit message of the PR which I use in `if` condition of my `main-job`. Now the issue here as pre_ci job always runs, I'll get workflow status as `success` whether  `main-job` runs or skips.

```
  pre_ci:
    name: Check Build Condition
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Project
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
      - name: "[Pull Request] Get commit message"
        id: pr_get_commit_message
        run: echo ::set-output name=pr_commit_message::$(git log --format=%B -n 1 HEAD^2)
    outputs:
      commit_message: ${{ steps.pr_get_commit_message.outputs.pr_commit_message }}


  main-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    needs: pre_ci
    if: ${{ (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && !contains(needs.pre_ci.outputs.commit_message, '#skipCI')) }}
    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: |
            echo "Main job executed"
```

Is there a way I can set the workflow status a `skip` if main-job skips

P.S screenshot of skipped workflow
[image]

Comment: What do you mean here? Workflows cannot be "skipped" - they either fail or succeed or canceled - but the canceled state is not controllable my you - it comes from GitHub.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Who said it can't be skipped? I have post the screenshot of my skipped workflow

Comment: maybe skipped jobs?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want the whole workflow status to be "skip" if a specific job inside it has been "skipped"? Wouldn't it be an option to use directly the [skipping workflow runs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs) commit messages?

Comment: @GuiFalourd https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs

this will allow us to skip the workflow by pass KEYWORD in commit message where as I am looking for a automated way by which a workflow should skip if a job is skip